# How to update table records in a database based on a table with the same table in another database?

Tags: postgresql, cross-database

Let's assume that I have `db1` and `db2`, two databases. I would like to perform a command of the like of

```
update db2.person p2
set p2.name = p1.name
from db1.person p1
where p1.id = p2.id;
```

This is possible in MySQL without any problems. I have great difficulty achieving it in PostgreSQL.

What I have tried:

```
create extension postgres_fdw;

create server theservername
foreign data wrapper postgres_fdw
options(host 'localhost', dbname 'thedbname', port '5432');

create user mapping for theuser
server theservername
options(user 'theusername', password 'thepassword');
```

And here I'm stuck, I don't know how to proceed. None of these troubles exist in MySQL. How can I overcome them in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps are following:

Step - 1: Create Extension

```
create extension postgres_fdw;
```

Step - 2: Create Server

```
create server theservername
foreign data wrapper postgres_fdw
options(host 'localhost', dbname 'thedbname', port '5432');
```

Step - 3: Create Foreign User Mapping for the server

```
create user mapping for theuser
server theservername
options(user 'theusername', password 'thepassword');
```

Step - 4: Create Foreign Table with same structure as in another DB

```
create foreign table "schema_name"."local_table_name"
(
id_ int;
...
-- field list same as foreign table in other db
)
server theservername
options(SCHEMA_NAME 'foreign_schema', TABLE_NAME 'foreign_name');
```

Now you can use `local_table_name` in your query just as local table. It will do all operations on remote db.

Your update query can be written like below:

```
update local_table_name p2
set name = p1.name
from person p1
where p1.id = p2.id;
```

Comment: the table name is person in both cases

Comment: I have created a foreign table named fperson

Comment: and now I do not have permission to run select count(*) from fperson;

Comment: create foreign table fperson(somecolumns) server migration1 options(schema_name 'public', table_name 'person');

Comment: As I have mentioned before, I have created a foreign table and now do not have permission to read from it

Comment: permission denied for foreign table fperson

Comment: I'm logged in with the user whom the server was mapped to

Comment: Sorry. The foreign table was created by postgres user. Removed it and attempted to create it for the user to whom this should be mapped. And it lacks the permission to do so as well.

Comment: ```GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER theservername TO theuser;```